# What is the best way to represent a map or train station line as a graph in code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, design-patterns, graph

so I was trying to represent a certain transport system and apply some search algorithms. The system consists of a number of stations, so I think they can act as vertices. while the lines between them are good for the edges. I do have a high level idea of what I wanna do and how the search might work but I am not able to translate that into code.

Do I use a class to represent the stations? and each station an object? a tuple to store the co-ordinates? I would love to get any guidance to how to actually translate implementing the algorithms and writing the program itself.

I am thinking about using C++ for this

Comment: Step one: Pick a language. That will colour just about everything else you'll do.

Comment: I am thinking C++, the STL has a lot of features I can use

Comment: 1. C++ STL has a "lot" of features, but the same can also be said for Python and Java. 2. There could be hundreds of ways to do the same task differently. It depends on what you want to achieve, like optimise space, or time, offer search for a broader region, etc

Answer (score 0):

you need at least a class Node/Station, then you need either 1. a class Graph that contains a list of weighted connections between 2 Nodes, or 2. a list of nodes and each nodes has a list of weighted connections with node pointers.

Usually you would want your graph API to be able to return the neighbors of a node* sorted by weights, so probably sort that by calling graph.build() after adding all the weights.

There is no real gain in adding "coordinates" for the stations, unless its a real application, as its much easier to just set costs between stations than trying to come up with good positions for stations, otherwise just draw yourself a station map and label the edges yourself.

I'm guessing you want something like graph.path(a, b), then with Dijkstra's algorithm you will easily be able to do that, I would recommend setting up the code to call the algo before coding too much, that way if you're about to represent the data in a bad way, you will know earlier.